# how to increase selected column with in google sheet using c# winform

Tags: c#, google-sheets

I am looking to increase Google sheet Column width i try below link from google app script but I cant understand
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoResizeColumns(Integer,Integer)
I need help in c# for same

Comment: Um... do you currently have any code for interacting with Google Sheets from C#?

Comment: yes hear is a link which code i use https://www.hardworkingnerd.com/how-to-read-and-write-to-google-sheets-with-c/

Comment: When you say `selected column`, do you mean the column that is currently selected in the UI? If that's the case, you'll need to use Apps Script for this, since information about current cell is only retrievable via bound script (see [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange)). If it's about resizing columns whose indexes you know, this is possible. But before posting an answer I'd like to clarify this.